# Frame extractor

Tags: java, time, extract, frame

So, I've been trying to create a frame extractor but, obviously, it doesn't work. Here's what it look likes

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.sql.Time;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

import org.bytedeco.javacv.FFmpegFrameGrabber;
import org.bytedeco.javacv.Frame;
import org.bytedeco.javacv.Java2DFrameConverter;

    public class FrameExtract {
    
    public static void main(String []args) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter the file name and path");
        Scanner filepath = new Scanner(System.in);
        String filename = filepath.nextLine();
        File myObj = new File(filename);
        System.out.println("Please enter the precise time of the frame you want to extract");
        Scanner timeex = new Scanner(System.in);
        Long timetoex = timeex.nextLong();
        Time timestamp = new Time(timetoex);
        FFmpegFrameGrabber frameGrabber = new FFmpegFrameGrabber(myObj.getAbsoluteFile());
        frameGrabber.start();
        Frame f;
        try {
            Java2DFrameConverter c = new Java2DFrameConverter();
            f = frameGrabber.grab();
            BufferedImage bi = c.convert(f);
            ImageIO.write(bi,"png", new File("D:\\img.png"));
            frameGrabber.stop();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

and the exceptions show this:

```
java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:864)

java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1485)

java.util.Scanner.nextLong(Scanner.java:2222)

java.util.Scanner.nextLong(Scanner.java:2182)

Eng.F.FrameExtract.main(FrameExtract.java:22)
```

I know there is problems like the code doesn't use the time properly, or even at all

Comment: and there is no Exception-Class (like `InputMismatchException`) or message involved? Anyway seems like a problem while reading long from standard input (like reading some letters instead of digits)

Comment: Well I changed the time declaration part, which had the most exception into this                                        
         System.out.println("Please enter (in seconds) the exact time of the frame you want to extract");
     Scanner timeex = new Scanner(System.in);
     String timetoex = timeex.nextLine();
     int time = Integer.parseInt(timetoex);

Comment: And it works (well a least I don't have exceptions anymore). Now all the programm needs to do is to extract a frame form the given second